# Joomla 4 namespacing and autoloading

Tags: custom-component, joomla-4.x, namespace

I've added the namespace line to my manifest xml: `<namespace>Mycompany\Component\Mycomponent</namespace>`

When I install the component, I'm not seeing any alias added to the `libraries/vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php` -- should Joomla regenerate that file with each component installed?

Is there any other places (besides just the namespaces in the classes themselved) that I need to register my namespace?

Comment: As @Sharky mentioned to you in his comment at your previous question: the Namespacemap Plugin should be turned on and that will update/create a new namespacemap for your component after a successful install.

Comment: @Zollie -- thanks. Is that plugin not enabled by default?

Comment: It is actually enabled by default and as it's description says: "Automatically builds and updates the libraries\autoload_psr4.php file that is used to autoload extensions."

Comment: I have not checked the newer alphas of J4 but earlier there were issues with updating the classmap at extension install: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/20953.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Zollie-- the plugin is enabled by default and does seem to work. You'd need to check the `libraries/autoload_psr4.php` to verify that your component's namespace (set in the new `namespace` parameter in the manifest xml) is being generated correctly.

The default namespace format for custom components is `DeveloperName\Component\ComponentName`.